# Uninstall Gnome 3.10 completly from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, gnome

When I installed GNOME 3.10 on my Ubuntu 13.10 system, there was problem with my GUI. After installing Gnome there are other problems as well.

If you have any idea how to uninstall gnome completely, and any idea on how to make Ubuntu 13.10 go back to a fresh installation state, then please help me. Even after I have uninstalled Gnome, the problems persist.

I want to say thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/462163/uninstall-gnome-completly-from-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 4):

Install Unity and Unity desktop back-

```
sudo apt-get install unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share activity-log-manager-common python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and reconfigurte lightDm by-

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

then  remove gnome it by using following commands -

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: in fact> sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell

Comment: @Chechus no but install unity and configuring it is also important.

Comment: i mean, there is a typo in the last command