# Revert from Gnome 3 to Unity

Tags: unity, gnome

Ok, so Ubuntu 14.04 came with Gnome 3 in it's repo and I tried to give it a go, and I didn't like it at all.
So I wanted to continue to use Unity desktop, but it kept freezing and I couldn't change background. Right click also isn't working on desktop.

Is there a way to delete all of Gnome 3 and reinstall Unity like it would be after fresh install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstall Gnome 3.10 completly from Ubuntu 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/386851/uninstall-gnome-3-10-completly-from-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: No. This isn't working. It says `E: Package 'activity-log-manager-common' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Open Terminal** or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

To **install Unity**
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity`

To **Remove Gnome**
`sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

and reboot the system `sudo reboot`

If followed above 3 commands, you should be greeted with Unity session after reboot. In case it still doesn't comes up, open terminal and execute `unity --replace`

*PS: by chance anything from gnome is left, follow https://askubuntu.com/a/244658/86467*

Comment: Have you tested it? Because removing ubuntu-gnome-desktop will also remove components that are needed by ubuntu-desktop...

Comment: Yes, it worked for me in past when I had similar issue. `ubuntu-desktop` is unity and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is gnome. It is straight. you may remove gnome first and install unity then after to be in safer side, you may do this into Ctrl+Alt+F1 (console mode).

Comment: I did this (including sudo unity --replace) and after reboot was shown the Unity login screen, however I can't log in. Syslog shows gnome-session Unable to find required component 'gnome-shell' :-(

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 17.10, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966916/148598) worked relatively well for me after rebooting (@Mayura's answer did not work for me).

1. `sudo apt install unity`
2. Reboot
3. At login screen, click the cog wheel next to the sign in button and select Unity.