# Is there a way to install Unity 7 in 17.10?

Tags: unity

Now, that Ubuntu 17.10 is out, and Unity 7 is replaced with Gnome 3, is there a way to install and use Unity7?

I know Unity is still in the repositories, so it should be possible, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do:

```
sudo apt install unity

sudo apt install unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  activity-log-manager appmenu-qt bamfdaemon compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas hud indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana libaccounts-glib0 libbamf3-2 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libcompizconfig0 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libdecoration0 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libframe6 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libglewmx1.13 libgrail6 libgsettings-qt1 libido3-0.1-0
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity1 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libsignon-glib1 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1
  libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 metacity-common
  nux-tools python3-blinker python3-bs4 python3-feedparser python3-html5lib python3-jwt python3-lxml python3-oauthlib python3-webencodings rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist session-migration
  session-shortcuts sgml-base shotwell shotwell-common system-config-printer thunderbird-gnome-support ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-asset-pool unity-control-center unity-greeter
  unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-schemas
  unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages
  unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-master-default
  unity-scopes-runner unity-services unity-session unity-settings-daemon zeitgeist-datahub
Suggested packages:
  lightdm unity-greeter-session-broadcast fcitx url-dispatcher python-blinker-doc python3-genshi python3-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc sgml-base-doc python3-smbc lightdm-remote-session-freerdp
  lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure remote-login-service tomboy
Recommended packages:
  systemd-services
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  activity-log-manager appmenu-qt bamfdaemon compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas hud indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana libaccounts-glib0 libbamf3-2 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libcompizconfig0 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libdecoration0 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libframe6 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libglewmx1.13 libgrail6 libgsettings-qt1 libido3-0.1-0
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity1 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libsignon-glib1 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1
  libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 metacity-common
  nux-tools python3-blinker python3-bs4 python3-feedparser python3-html5lib python3-jwt python3-lxml python3-oauthlib python3-webencodings rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist session-migration
  session-shortcuts sgml-base shotwell shotwell-common system-config-printer thunderbird-gnome-support ubuntu-touch-sounds unity unity-asset-pool unity-control-center unity-greeter
  unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-schemas
  unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages
  unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-master-default
  unity-scopes-runner unity-services unity-session unity-settings-daemon zeitgeist-datahub
0 upgraded, 116 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

After that you need to log out and log back in and select unity a desktop environment (the small cog-wheel beside the sign in button).

Comment: Have you tested it, and on which flavor? What was the output of that command?

Comment: This will install unity7 and all around it, had to log out and change the DE in the login and thats it. output i cant tell you right now as im in the process of installing 17.10 on bare metal.

Comment: @mikewhatever http://paste.ubuntu.com/25788716/

Comment: While this is possible, note that unity is in the _universe_ repository now and will almost certainly be removed entirely in 18.04. So it is not something that should be recommended to others to do. If one wants to run Unity, the best thing to do would be to run 16.04, for now.

Comment: Indeed and i have to add, while you can even go back and use lightdm I would not advise it, it resulted in a lot of crashes internally and error messages popping up.

Comment: @dobey Unity 7.5 is still available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in both current daily build and future planned release.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It was not clear that would be the case when I made the comment, and it is still moved to universe out of main, afaik.

Comment: I have Unity (from a 16.04 upgrade to 17.04) but adwaita theme and others don't work, and compiz won't do any of the effects