# Global menu bar in Ubuntu gnome 17.10

Tags: unity, 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, menu-bar

Does anyone know if it is possible at all to display the global menubar in apps from the main ubuntu repository? I have found very odd that is missing in apps like pinta (show below), GIMP or Gpaint

[image]

While present (not as neat as in Unity) in other apps not in the the main Ubuntu repository (e.g. TexStudio).

[image]

I am aware of the existence of an extension to show the global menu bar (as shown in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966989/ubuntu-17-10-windows-menu-in-top-bar)), however, I want to know why some apps are still showing the menubar while other are not and, most importantly, whether there is a solution for that.

Comment: What's your GIMP version? Menu bar is there in my set-up as usual.

Comment: It's GIMP 2.8. I've found odd because the menubar is present in some programs while absent in others

Answer (score 1):

If you have have installed [Gnome Global Application Menu(HUD for Gnome)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) extension mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967056/480481) to the other question you've linked, you'll need to reset a couple of `gsettings` keys after disabling/uninstalling the extension to restore normalcy.

Open Terminal and run the following commands

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules
```

Then reboot.

(See "Uninstallation instructions" [here](https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu))

Comment: this appears to be indeed the solution. When I run the first command, however, I got `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`.

Comment: @BCArg Looks like your gsettings is broken, see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

Comment: Yes indeed. Do you think it is safe to run the commands from the accepted answer? If I do  `ls /usr/local/lib/` I will get: `libgbtools.a  libgbtools.la  libhts.a  libhts.so  libhts.so.1.5  libhts.so.2  pkgconfig  python2.7  python3.6  R  warsaw`. I have installed anaconda3 and the path to it is appended on my `$PATH`.

Comment: @BCArg To be honest I have no idea whether it's safe in your case :(

Comment: @ pomsky Yes I think this should be more carefully evaluated before I mess up my system. Will upvote your answer, thanks for getting me on the way.