# Ubuntu gnome 17.10 - safe to reset gsettings?

Tags: 17.10, dconf, gsettings

I have a while ago installed a very [useless extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) to emulate the unity top/menur bar in gnome, which was ruined the menubar in a few applications running on my machine, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023618/menubar-in-libreoffice-ubuntu-17-10-gnome?noredirect=1#comment1663072_1023618) and in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009076/global-menu-bar-in-ubuntu-gnome-17-10/1023664#1023664).

I have then uninstalled the extension and wanted to restore normalcy with:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules
```

However, when I ran those commands, I get:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

Which probably means that my gsettings is broken.

I have then found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins) where they show how to reset the gsettings. However, I am slightly afraid that it can somehow ruin some applications I have running on my machine. After all, my machine works smoothly, just a few applications (libreoffice, pinta, gimp) are not displaying the menubar.

My question is. Is it generally safe to reset the gsettings, as show in the above shown question? Is it possible to assess safety of it by running a few commands on my machine and assessing the output?

Thanks in advance