# How to reduce menu/title bar screen space in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, titlebar, menu-bar

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. In my previous version, the title, status, *and* the "File ..." menu were all bundled together in a neat little bar for every maximized window.

Now they are all separate, and as you can see they are taking up a huge amount of screen real estate. Is there any way to get some of it back?

[image: Two really big bars]
<sup>**2 big bars**</sup>

[image: Three really big bars!]
<sup>**3 big bars**</sup>

Comment: Your two screenshots are the same.

Comment: Please reupload the 2nd screenshot and provide a link to it so that I can embed it.

Comment: Try PixelSaver Gnome shell extension? See https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wasted screen space due to multiple horizontal bars at the top when an application is open in GNOME desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966989/ubuntu-17-10-windows-menu-in-panel) for a global menubar option, but warning: the solution is pretty buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this issue is only on Firefox, go to the browser's menu and click Customize. At the bottom, there is a dropdown menu called Toolbars. Your menu bar will be selected. Deselect it.