# Returning removed feature (merged title/menu/top bar)

Tags: 18.04

I want ubuntu 16 merged top/title and menu bar, back. what should I do?

Comment: See [_"How to reduce menu/title bar screen space in 18.04?"_](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036217/504066) and the comment about the Pixelsaver extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wasted screen space due to multiple horizontal bars at the top when an application is open in GNOME desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966989/ubuntu-17-10-windows-menu-in-panel) for the menubar option, but the solution is pretty buggy.