# Show application menus in top menu bar at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, appmenu

I've just updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.

In Ubuntu 16.04 there was setting which moved application menus to the top menu bar

[image]

I can't find this setting at Ubuntu 18.04, and my app windows look like this :

[image]

It is awful, because now there is 3-times less useful space at the top of my window!

How can I collapse 3 lines at the top to one line in top bap, like in Ubuntu 16.04?

UPD: this is not only about VSCode. This behavior affects all apps with menu bar including terminal, LibreOffice, etc.

Comment: Before installing Unity in 18.04 , you should have a look at [Unite Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/). It's not 100%, but I think it's doing a great job.

Comment: @pLumo not exactly. I don't want to use unity instead of gnome, just want to change behavior about menu bar. Although using unity solves this.

Comment: Then use Unite Gnome Extension that I linked in my second comment. There is no better way as far as I know. If you find out, I'd be happy to know :-)

Comment: @pLumo yeah, this extemsion is useful. It removes app title bar, but doesn't remove app menu bar, so I still have 2 bars instaead of 1. Also it has strange behavior with chrome where I have 2  sets of window buttons :)

Comment: @pLumo Will use it untill find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: That is strange, my chromium works just fine with Unite. But I'm on 20.04 which has newer Gnome version. It improved a lot ... Imo, 18.04 was not usable... I switched from Unity to Gnome only with 19.04.

Comment: Found a way to disable it using chrome settings

Comment: I give an updated answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1236381/352251, because this current thread is incorrectly closed to me. I do not consider that thread as an answer of what you are asking here, because things change in 18.04 as ubuntu developer said here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1131664/comments/61