# How to move the ribbon into the Top bar in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, tweak, top-bar

I would like the top bar to include the ribbon, which is File, Edit, View etc.
Similar to Mac OS.
Then it would also be best if I could move the 'time' to the right side instead of the middle.
Any information on how to tweak the top bar would be much appreciated.
My version is Ubuntu 20.04, the Gnome Desktop Environment, and I would not like the title bar of my window to be merged with the top bar like in Unity.

Awais.

Comment: It's not possible. I use the brilliant [**Unite** Gnome Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) and this is as far as it gets.

Comment: There [used be a GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/966989/480481) for this, but it's unmaintained for a long time. So the extension is unlikely to work with 20.04.