# Compiz shortcuts not working on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I've installed CompizConfig Settings Manager and confirmed my key bindings for grid are set. No matter what I set the binding to in the settings manager the only binding that will work is `Super` + `left`/`right`.

How can I get Compiz to work? I'm aiming to get it so I can have a window take up 75% of the screen using the 'Cycle through multiple sizes' option on compiz.

Comment: Experiencing this also, I think it's a generalisation of this bug report, so I've left a comment there. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1727842

Comment: thanks for your input! I was getting concerned it was just me. my keyboard volume keys work, I've not tried the others yet. weird.

Comment: Did the problem occur after upgrading to ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: this was a fresh install

Comment: I just upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 and now have the same problem

Comment: Do you have unity installed in your system?  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10)

Comment: I did not. I'll have a go. Is there anything for gnome that would do this for me? I'm considering using i3 at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.10 won't use compiz by default.  When you try to run `compiz` in a terminal it lets you know that another manager is running.  You can use `compiz --replace` to stop the old one and use compiz.
This is while I'm running on X-Org still.  I don't know if this will work while wayland is running.

Answer (score 0):

Removing following configuration files seemed to fix the problem (in the context of an upgrade to 17.10, but probably the solution applies here too):

- `~/.compiz`
- `~/.gconf`
- `~/.gnome*`
- `~/.kde`

For example:

```
mkdir ~/backupFixSO970617
mv ~/.compiz ~/.gconf ~/.gnome* ~/.kde ~/backupFixSO970617
```

If this does not work, you can also add `~/.config` to the list, but be careful as this folder also contains a lot of application related configuration files, thus I advice to make a backup (mv) instead of deleting (rm) all folder directly.

Source: [stackoverflow.com - 
Keyboard shortcuts stop working after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972940/keyboard-shortcuts-stop-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-17-10#comment1565882_972940)