# How to uninstall Unity safely from an Ubuntu 17.10 Upgrade

Tags: apt, unity, gnome, upgrade, 17.10

I have chosen to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 desktop to Ubuntu 17.10 and found out that Unity Desktop isn’t completely removed after the upgrade.

As we all know that, since Ubuntu abandoned the Unity desktop, there’s no reason to keep any part or the program or feature. So I decided to completely remove Unity from Ubuntu 17.10.

I know the basic process but my question is: is it too risky to remove Unity because Ubuntu is core OS and some of its package depend on them?

How can I safely remove Ubuntu Unity desktop without breaking anything?

Comment: Hi, this is an opinion rather than fact, but, personally, I would wait a while before you remove Unity. There are some /small/ issues with Wayland [see the threads in this forum] as some applications don't yet fully support Wayland. You may find you need to flip back to Unity sometime. 
And is we're only talking about "desktop environments" I'd leave it there just for now.

However, I think this is the answer you're looking for :
From the terminal: `sudo apt-get remove unity*` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove` so nothing stays.

Comment: [Here is](https://askubuntu.com/a/966916/20054) the list of packages related to Unity. Removing them shouldn't break anything.

Comment: after that does i have to install functional Ubuntu desktop with GDM3 manager  `sudo apt install ubuntu-session gdm3`

Comment: I don't think so, those packages should be installed by default in 17.10.