# Is there a Ubuntu 17.10 that does not have GNOME desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I personally don't like GNOME so just wanted to know if 17.10 is a GNOME-only version or if there is a non-GNOME version.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: k/l/xubuntu , lots of options. You can install multiple WM such as openbox, fluxbox, awesomewm .... A simple google search will give you many choices.

Comment: Also MATE, Budgie. You can even [use Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [Ubuntu MATE 17.10](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-artful-final-release/) version, or you can use [Kubuntu 17.10](https://kubuntu.org/tag/kubuntu-17-10/).