# Unity-tweak-tool on 17.10 not working

Tags: unity

I recently switched from Linux Mint to Ubuntu 17.10 and I would like to make some adjustments to the environment (e.g. configure alt+tab to only rotate between applications in current workspace).

I read that unity-tweak-tool is a popular tool and it seems to have the options I want, but I can't get it to work. I tried installing through the terminal as well as the software center (weirdly, after installing from the terminal the tool is not installed in the software center). The application does not appear in the launcher but I can start it from the command line. However, changing its settings does not have any result on my system.

On launching the tool, I receive the warning:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
```

I have no clue what this refers to, but it is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1575485.

I also had compiz-config-settings-manager installed. I tried enabling the unity plugin there, which did not have any effect. I also tried removing the application, without result.

Comment: Have you installed unity in your computer as well?  Ubuntu 17.10 runs over Gnome by default.

Comment: Ah, that would be embarrassing.  How can I check this? The package unity is installed, but I haven't changed my environment

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I've been running to gnome for so long it doesn't matter.  You could try to search askubuntu for 17.10 and unity

Comment: @Scipio You should find an option to switch session (a cogwheel or something like that) in your login screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Gnome-tweak-tools works, so I suppose that settles it ;)

Comment: @pomsky I think you specifically need to install unity, as described in [https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10)

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes, of course. I thought OP [did already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984680/unity-tweak-tool-on-17-10-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1584311_984680).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

17.10 uses Gnome, not Unity. Try Gnome Tweak Tool.

Install from here

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/

Ref : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/gnome-tweak-tool-renamed-gnome-tweaks