# Display tray/taskbar date on RIGHT handside in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I'm using now Ubuntu 17.10 in work and Ubuntu 16.04 in home. In new Ubuntu 17.10 gui switched to GNOME where you have date in the middle of your taskbar. In previous releases there were Unity as a default environment and date always display on right hand side. How can I change GNOME taskbar to show date on right handside?

Comment: You can switch Ubuntu 17.10 to use Unity: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10