# Why was Unity removed from 18.04?

Tags: unity, 18.04

I searched for the answer but still unable to find why was Unity removed from 18.04. It seemed to be a descent UI, with all the related connectivity, and very well designed short-cuts.

Can someone please point me to why it was removed from 18.04. Somehow, I am not very accustomed to gnome, or rather I am very used to Unity now.

Thanks and Regards,

Abhay

Comment: A quick google search would have led you to this: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/why-did-ubuntu-drop-unity-mark-shuttleworth-explains which explains the reasoning, quoting Mark Shuttleworth.

Comment: You can still install and use Unity: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966915/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-7-in-17-10

Comment: Takes about a week and you wont look back at Unity :P

Comment: I tried gnome, and went back to Unity. The best thing about Unity is the integration of applications with the desktop. It was nice and would be very much missed.

Comment: Gnome has improved under Ubuntu and will no doubt improve even more. But in the meantime I still prefer Unity under 16.04 and 18.04 which are the only two distros I use. Well plus Lubuntu 16.04 inside virtualbox but that's a different can of worms.

Comment: Yeah ... Event the short-cuts are so intuitive ... Alt+Space+X ... and Maximize ... With Gnome, I have to use arrow keys once I do Alt+Space ... thats a bit down-turning ... :( ... I really wish the usabilility aspect of Unity to be brought down to Gnome ...