# Old-style notifications in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, notify-osd

I'm using Gnome 3 in 18.04 LTS and I want to have the notifications the way they were before, I mean the bubble fading when hovered.

[image: notification style]

Is there a way to set them back?

Comment: when you say the way they were before, did you mean 16.04 when using Unity?

Comment: I guess. I don't remember which release made the change.

Comment: Gnome returned as the default in 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revert from Gnome 3 to Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452411/revert-from-gnome-3-to-unity)

Comment: Actually I installed Gnone because it came with Unity by default, and obviously I prefer Gnome rather than Unity.

Comment: Are you sure that's right? 18.04 by default installs Gnome not Unity.

Comment: I am. Anyway, why would this matter? Is it a desktop or a notify-osd issue?