# Uninstall Gnome completly from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: server, 14.04, gnome

When I installed GNOME on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system, there was problem with my GUI. After installing Gnome there are other problems as well.

If you have any idea how to uninstall gnome completely, and any idea on how to make Ubuntu 14.04 LTS go back to a fresh installation state, then please help me. Even after I have uninstalled Gnome, the problems persist.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `tasksel` which is an ncurses based tool that allows you to install groups of packages ( used in the debian and ubuntu minimal installers).

After launching the tool from your terminal you will be given a list of package groups. to uninstall gnome simple untick ( using the spacebar) `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` this should give you a clean slate to work with once applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get -f purge argyll dconf-editor deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles \
deja-dup-backend-s3 evolution evolution-common evolution-indicator \
evolution-plugins fonts-cantarell gdm gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 \
gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 \
gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 \
gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 \
gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 \
gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 \
gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-tracker-0.16 \
gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gjs gnome-backgrounds \
gnome-color-manager gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data \
gnome-documents gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-icon-theme-full \
gnome-online-accounts gnome-online-miners gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon \
gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sushi \
gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-tweak-tool \
grilo-plugins-0.2 gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs-backends-goa itstool \
libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libcolord-gtk1 libenca0 libencode-locale-perl \
liberror-perl libevolution libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libgdm1 \
libgif4 libgjs0e libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgrilo-0.2-1 libgsf-1-114 \
libgsf-1-common libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 \
libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl \
libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl \
libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libicc2 libimdi0 \
libio-html-perl libiptcdata0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl \
libmail-spf-perl libmediaart-1.0-0 libmozjs-24-0 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmutter0c \
libnet-http-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libnss-myhostname libpst4 \
libreoffice-style-tango libsys-hostname-long-perl libtracker-extract-0.16-0 \
libtracker-miner-0.16-0 libtracker-sparql-0.16-0 libwww-perl \
libwww-robotrules-perl libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-xf86dri0 libxcb-xv0 \
libxml2-utils libytnef0 libzapojit-0.0-0 mcp-account-manager-goa mutter \
mutter-common plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo \
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text python-boto python-cloudfiles python-requests \
python-urllib3 re2c sa-compile spamassassin spamc tracker tracker-extract \
tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils ubuntu-gnome-default-settings \
ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-trusty \
unoconv xserver-xephyr xsltproc yelp-tools zsync
```

Comment: Would not `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge libgtk-3-0 libgtk2.0-0` not be simpler?

Comment: @dobey: this removed all of the remaining gnome packages!

Comment: @Air You can re-install the `ubuntu-desktop` package afterwards to pull in anything that was uninstalled, and included in the default install.

Comment: I meant it like this - @dobey: Great! This *finally* removed all of the remaining gnome packages! Hurray!